# How to tap into Quick Campaign life cycle

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I would like to run custom code when a Quick Campaign is completed (distributed the activities).

Unfortunately I don't see how I could create either a plugin or a workflow regarding Quick Campaign.

I have an SMS service that I send data extracted from customized letter activities. The code queries all appropriate contact activities, so I can't run it one-by-one for each created activity. (If I had 10 activities, wf would run 10 times and send 10 sms' to everyone).

There's the option of overhauling the code to work on a per-activity basis, but that would cost time and performance.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I'm misinterpreting the question, this will be a useless suggestion.  Can stored procedures help in any way?  At least with those, you can run them on a schedule with minimal impact on your system.  Only problem with using SQL directly is no record creation and no WF execution.

Comment: @DrewQuick is this approach a supported one? I don't believe directly interacting with CRM's db is supported. Will it export/import with the solution?